# Проблема с Slider Revolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

При применении фильтров на товары Woocommerce происходит ошибка слайдера.
После того, как применяется один из фильтров на товары на странице магазина исчезает Слайдер. После перезагрузки страницы слайдер вновь появляется.
Ошибок в консоли никаких нет.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обновить слайдер и Wp до последней версии.

Comment: Все обновлено до последних версий.